# A practical question about probabilities and NS&I bonds investment

Tags: probability, lotteries

Here is a rather practical question, I and my [son](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/316918/tciur) have different opinions about, please bear with me, it's a **probability question**:

> With NS&I bonds, is it better to buy many smaller value bonds or fewer (eventually one) larger value bonds?

For example, say you have $£1000$ available, is it better to buy

- $10$ bonds with $£100$ value each or
- one bond of $£1000$ value?

Options:

- I say - one larger value is better
- My son says - it doesn't matter, applying [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).

By **better** I mean the chance of winning anything, no difference between large and small wins.

**A short intro.**

[NS&I bonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premium_Bond) are like a perpetual lottery in UK. Each $£1$ buys one lottery number. A bond (or bond value) consists of one or more such numbers, technically the smallest value is $£25$ or $25$ numbers. The number structure is like ($||$ means concatenation)
$$\text{up to3 digits } || \text{ 2 characters } || \text{ 6 digits } \tag{1}$$
for example $295\text{PC}150165$. The numbers are consecutive, e.g. $£100$ will buy a bond value of $£100$ with a possible sequence like (again, this is an example)
$$300\text{PC}000001 - 300\text{PC}000100$$
Unfortunately, you can't choose the numbers, the system does it for you. The maximum number of tickets one can ever hold is $50000$, in one large value bond of $£50000$ or in many smaller - doesn't matter, $50000$ is the upper limit. Winning numbers are selected randomly and uniformly.

**Why I think "one larger value is better".**

If I group the winning numbers, for the last almost one year, by the $2$ characters (let's call it **a basket**) in the middle (see $(1)$), I get a pretty uniform distribution (more or less) per basket, here is an example:

[image]

There are $529$ such baskets. Uniformity of the random selection of the winning numbers makes the spread uniform per basket. We can "approximate" each such basket with **an independent lottery**. Buying a bond (any value, $50000$ upper limit fits into one basket) means buying tickets in one basket/lottery (I haven't seen cross baskets purchesments, let's assume it's not possible). Then the problem is similar to

> Is it better to buy tickets in one lottery or many lotteries, given all lotteries are similar?

**Similar** in this case means each lottery has maximum $M$ tickets possible and $n$ random draws are performed. This is [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution). The answer is **buy all in one lottery**. Let's consider a simple example of $2$ lotteries (and then by induction ...) and the intuition of even splitting. I can buy $2k$ tickets, either all in one lottery or $k$ tickets per lottery. The chances of winning are

- **All in one lottery case** $$1-\frac{\binom{M-2k}{n}}{\binom{M}{n}} \tag{2}$$
- **[$k$ tickets per lottery case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)** considering independence $$1-\frac{\binom{M-k}{n}}{\binom{M}{n}} + 1-\frac{\binom{M-k}{n}}{\binom{M}{n}} -\left(1-\frac{\binom{M-k}{n}}{\binom{M}{n}}\right)^2=\\
  1-\left(\frac{\binom{M-k}{n}}{\binom{M}{n}}\right)^2 \tag{3}$$

Then
$$(2) \geq (3) \iff 
\frac{\binom{M-2k}{n}}{\binom{M}{n}} \leq \left(\frac{\binom{M-k}{n}}{\binom{M}{n}}\right)^2 \iff
\binom{M-2k}{n}\cdot \binom{M}{n} \leq \binom{M-k}{n}^2 \iff\\
(M-2k)(M-2k-1)...(M-2k-n+1)\cdot M(M-1)...(M-n+1) \leq (M-k)^2(M-k-1)^2...(M-k-n+1)^2 \iff\\
\left(1-\frac{k}{M-k}\right)\left(1-\frac{k}{M-k-1}\right)...\left(1-\frac{k}{M-k-n+1}\right) \leq \left(1-\frac{k}{M}\right)\left(1-\frac{k}{M-1}\right)...\left(1-\frac{k}{M-n+1}\right)$$
which is true, compared term by term. **All in one lottery** in this case is similar to **all in one basket** or **one larger value bond is better**.

This is also backed by the observation that large value bonds are [leading the winning board](https://www.nsandi.com/prize-checker/winners). Here is a histogram from the data this March:
[image]

**Why my son thinks "it doesn't matter".**

The winning odds per basket aren't really independent, which is fair, since I only assumed it. Also, if we "round" the winning odds per ticket to a value $p$ (NS&I suggests the odds of winning anything are $1$ to $34500$), then:

- **All in one lottery case** $$1-(1-p)^{2n} \tag{4}$$
- **[$k$ tickets per lottery case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)** considering independence $$1-(1-p)^{n} + 1-(1-p)^{n} -\left(1-(1-p)^{n}\right)^2=\\
  1-(1-p)^{2n} \tag{5}$$

final result is the same.

---

Who is right, thoughts?

P.S. This should be treated as a probability problem, not an investment advice!

P.P.S. A bit of brainstorming and the Python code to produce the spreadsheet (as per the screenshot) are available [here](https://github.com/rtybase/ml-ai-stats/tree/master/g-dist-vs-hg-dist). Historical winning numbers can be downloaded from [here](https://www.nsandi.com/get-to-know-us/winning-bonds-downloads).

Comment: It makes no difference.  If you buy £1000 worth of premium bonds, you get 1000 numbers each equally likely to win a prize next moth and every future month until you cash them in.  It does not matter whether the numbers are consecutive or split into small blocks: you get the same number of entries into the prize draw and so the same probabilities of winning.

Comment: @Henry Since I don't know an NS&I bond from a *giraffe*, you have to take this comment with **some salt**.  Seems like the *hidden* issue around risk-*attitude* (i.e. averse, neutral, or seeking) is being ducked.  Since risk-neutral makes the issue meaningless, and since risk-averse can hide behind : leave the money in the bank, assume risk-seeking (e.g. for compulsive gambler, (1/10) chance of winning $\$10$ is worth $\$1.20$).  From this context, which alternative would be mathematically preferable to the risk-seeker?

Comment: @Henry I think, given the numbers are large and limits are small, advantage is negligible. Here is another analogy. Imagine I  buy half of the tickets in one lottery and zero tickets in the other. With a single draw per lottery, I have $0.5$ chance of winning. If I buy one fourth of tickets in one and one fourth in another, with a single draw per lottery, the chance of winning is $0.25 + 0.25 - 0.25\cdot 0.25$.

Comment: @rtybase - there is only one prize draw each month, with 3 million winning numbers last month.  So your argument about splitting between lotteries does not apply here

Comment: @user2661923 - the risk issue is a slight distraction: two numbers win £1 million each month (allowing dreams) but virtually all prizes are worth £25; you can win and I have won multiple times in the same month with different numbers. The expected interest rate is currently 1% per annum and tax-free, anomalously higher than banks currently pay in interest to depositors (this was not always the case).  So the bonds are currently highly attractive to moderately risk adverse savers. See https://www.nsandi.com/products/premium-bonds

Comment: @Henry to what extent this analogy doesn't apply? Do a random and uniform drawing over a large set, split the set into two. What makes the result different from the random drawings over the two smaller sets? Independence argument I guess. Can this be estimated? I'd try a Monte-Carlo simulation in Python, but I need a spare set of hands :) ... So far, 3000000/529 = 5671 winning numbers per basket, not too far from what the screenshot of the spreadsheet in the question is showing.

Comment: Also, @Henry, for the sake of the experiment, your winning numbers, do they belong to larger value bonds? Do a histogram, I'd like to see the result ... My winning numbers tend to belong to larger value bonds, 1000+.

Comment: @rtybase My winning numbers tend to come from larger bonds, for the simple reason that the large majority of my overall numbers are part of larger bonds.  Sometimes I win with £25 and £50 bonds (reinvested previous prizes) and occasionally I have a succession of such wins.  This is not is obviously inconsistent with the relative proportion of the amounts I have in larger and smaller bonds.

Comment: @Henry, right. For the experimentation purposes, I purchased small and large values throughout the last 2 years. This is one of the observations that dragged my attention. I do not differentiate between large and small wins, the chance is 1 to 34500, according to NS&I.